# ObjC category on typedef class: "cannot find interface declaration for 'typedefname'"

Tags: objective-c, typedef, objective-c-category

This code gives me the error `Cannot find interface declaration for 'OGWView'`:

```
typedef SKNode OGWView;

@interface OGWView (Category)
@end
```

Why? Shouldn't the category work just as well with a typedef name?

PS: I know I can fix this with a #define (or by using the original class name) but I'm really more interested in understanding why it isn't possible to create a category on a typedef class.

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is (I suspect that the compiler is simply not looking for a type there), but this seems like a good thing to disallow to me. Why would you ever want to mask what you are extending?

Comment: Because I want to extend different but similar classes (depending on current build config) with the same code. I think it won't work because the ObjC runtime simply isn't typedef-aware when it comes to categories, meaning the typedef isn't a registered runtime class, only the original class is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer to this question is that you have 2 different kinds of symbol. I believe the typedef is an object and you are trying to use it as a class symbol.

depending on the order of declaration you get different warnings suggesting as much:

```
typedef NSObject Foo;
@class Foo;
```

yields:

> Redefinition of forward class 'Foo' of a typedef name of an object type is ignored

```
@class Foo;
typedef NSObject Foo;
```

yields:

> Redefinition of 'Foo' as different kind of symbol

Answer (score 3):

Replace `typedef` with `@compatibility_alias`

```
@compatibility_alias SKNode OGWView;
```